# GIT & Laravel stopping certain files

Tags: php, git, laravel

I've been running a project written in Laravel which has been fun to use.

The setup I use is the vagrant box Homestead configuration so I do the majority of my work on my local machine and push up to the development server once its ready to go. During the installation I had to push up the logs & vendor folder for it to work properly but now I'm at a stage where every commit I do via the command line includes `storage/logs/laravel.log` which when I then pull down it asks me to stash/commit on the server because they're different.

I've added it to the .gitignore file in the root directory of the project and it looks like this:

```
/node_modules
/public/storage
/.idea
Homestead.json
Homestead.yaml
/storage/logs/
/vendor/
```

Vendor doesn't cause me any problems unless I make changes to it so its not much of a bother, its just the logs which will not stop going up. If I use a GUI tool, I can manually tell it not to go up but I want to get it to the point that I can use the terminal to push it up and not worry about logs need stashing on the server.

I believe this is the same for the `.env` so I imagine a solution will work for both. I have also noticed that PHPStorm have said they're ignored but tracked with git if that helps.

Comment: I think what you're looking for is a `.gitkeep` file in your `logs` directory, and a rule to ignore any logs in there - `logs/*.log`. You should not be versioning log files.

Comment: the .gitkeep is not in the /storage/logs folder just another ignore, should i manually add one, if so is there a reference i can look at?

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look at the Laravel repo on GitHub, you'll find the following .gitignore file in the storage directory:

https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/storage/logs/.gitignore

This comes with the default installation to mark the logs directory as ignored. If you've deleted this by mistake, you should be able to reinstate it and resolve the issue you're having.

Just as importantly though, your workflow isn't following best practice. With respect to "Vendor doesn't cause me and problems unless i make changes to it" - you should *never* make changes to your vendor directory. This folder is home to third-party packages and plugins, modifying them directly causes multiple issues, chief amongst them:

1. You can no longer update a modified package without breaking your application.
2. Other developers won't be able to replicate your installation easily.

In fact, the vendor directory shouldn't be versioned at all. The best way to handle the files within it is using a package manager, [like Composer](https://getcomposer.org/), to do it all for you. This means you can easily switch between different versions of your packages and, by versioning only the composer files, other developers can run `composer install` or `composer update` to synchronise their development environment to yours quickly and accurately.

Comment: My apologies, i when i meant by changes i did meant with the composer.json file which modifies the vendor folder, appreciate the warning though.

Comment: Also noted that the /storage/log does contain a git ignore similar to the link provided  : 
*
!.gitignore

Comment: Ah, composer.json makes much more sense. Did you have any luck with ignoring logs by creating that .gitignore?